# proxychains can't load process?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js

> I use brew install proxychains-ng and edit *proxychains.conf* file 
>   and change socks4 127.0.0.1 9080 to **socks5 127.0.0.1 1080**
>   open the shadowsocks

then run zsh `$proxychains nvm install v6.0.0`

console:

```
[proxychains] config file found: /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains- ng/4.11/etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
proxychains can't load process....: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an https proxy, e.g., use polipo's port 8123 to proxy socks5's port 1080

You can do it like below

```
https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:8123 nvm ls-remote
```