# proxychains can't load process

Tags: networking, proxy

Recently, I got a problem with proxychains.　And I wonder know why, I found a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928903/proxychains-cant-load-process), but there is not more explamation for this issue.

```
master proxychains4 composer update -vvv                                                                     mn52.com
[proxychains] config file found: /home/shane/.proxychains/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
proxychains can't load process....: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928903/proxychains-cant-load-process

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the full path of the command to proxychains4, such as "proxychains4 /usr/local/bin/compoer update -vvv", try "which composer" and you will see the full path.